# How can I use Html.DisplayFor inside of an iterator?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am *loving* MVC 2.  The whole thing just fits the web so well.

There is one piece of functionality, however, that I am unable to coax out of the `Html.DisplayFor()` function:

```
<@ Page Inherits="ViewPage<IEnumerable<Foo>>">

<% foreach(var item in Model) { %>

    <%: Html.DisplayFor(item.BarBaz) %>

<% } %>
```

I need to be able to use the DisplayTemplate for this value.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out.  How stupid of me.

This works:

```
<@ Page Inherits="ViewPage<IEnumerable<Foo>>">

<% foreach(var item in Model) { %>

    <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => item.BarBaz) %>

<% } %>
```

However, this will not work correctly for Html.HiddenFor and Html.ValueFor.  In particular, `Html.HiddenFor(m => item.NullableDecimal)` will render as `<input name="NullableDecimal" value="0" />` and `Html.ValueFor(m => item.NullableDecimal, "0.00##)` will render as `0.00##`.  However, if you apply a   `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00########}"` to your view model, then it will suddenly work.  For this reason, you're probably best off using `Html.Display`, `Html.Hidden`, and `Html.Value` extensions, since you're less likely to run into scenarios where things fail when someone makes a non-local change.

Comment: I think, I am even more stupid, as I am not sure how to interpret this. The lambda formal parameter m is not used in the expression. So is this only there because it is required by _DisplayFor_? Also, I expected that `@Html.Display(item.BarBaz)` would work just as well, but that renders nothing.

Comment: @R.Schreurs It seems the lambda needs to be a `Func` expression that takes the model's type as a parameter, but it can return anything.

Answer (score 12):

You can accomplish it by getting away from the foreach and using a regular for loop:

```
 <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) { %>

    <%: Html.DisplayFor(p=> p.ElementAt(i).BarBaz) %>

 <%} %>
```

Another option would be to create a PartialView that took an Foo object and only displayed the information that you wanted.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       Html.RenderPartial("FooBarBazLine", item);
   } %>
```

Comment: I agree that option 2 is a better solution.  I just included option 1 as I thought of it first and didn't really have any reason to remove it as it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but i guess that someone can get benefits from my solution:

**Aspx view**

```
<%@ Page Inherits="ViewPage<IEnumerable<Foo>>" %>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => item) %>

<% } %>
```

**Razor view**

```
@model IEnumerable<Foo>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    Html.DisplayFor(m => item)
}
```

Since `DisplayFor` accepts an implicit typed lambda, we can directly indicate the instance to display in the loop.

Finally, i'm agree with [Anders E. Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210066/anders-e-andersen)'s answer for the template usage

Comment: Thanks for sharing =D I was sooo focused on always having to go (x => Model.Yada) inside the expression...  sometimes you just need someone else to open you eyes =D Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Html.DisplayFor can automatically iterate over collections, displaying a partial view for each element in the collection.

The first thing you need to do is create an actual model class, with the collection being a property of the class.

```
public class Bar
{
    public IEnumerable<Foo> foo { get; set; }
}
```

Return this class from your controller instead of the raw collection.

Secondly you need a display template for the Foo class. Display templates are partial views that need to be placed in the folder `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`.

Edit: You can have them in your controller subfolder of Views as well if you want to limit the template to a particular controller. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841787/mvc-template-from-folder-other-than-default-editortemplates-displaytemplates) for more information.

Here is an example in razor syntax:

```
@model YourNameSpace.Foo
<p>@Model.BarBaz</p>
```

Save it as `Foo.cshtml` in the `DisplayTemplates` folder given above.

This template is pretty simple because it is based on your example where you are only displaying a string, but if the collection elements where a class with its own properties you could create a more elaborate template.

Now in the original view, you can get rid of the loop entirely and just write

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.foo)
```

Notice `foo` is the name of the property in your new model class that contains the old collection you looped over before.

DisplayFor will automatically know that the `foo` property is of type (collection of) `Foo` and pick up the `Foo.cshtml` template in the `DisplayTemplates` folder and show it once for each element in `foo`.

Comment: Imagine you have tons of models, having lists like this **IEnumerable<OneOfThousandEntities>**. Are you going to create one template per one-of-thousand-entities? All you need is just generic template for basic types, like string, integer, boolean, etc..

Comment: You don't really need bar do you, in the event the foo collection is accessible, say, statically? Or it is just a local variable?

Answer (score 1):

In Razor I am using

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CreatedDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just be careful that a DisplayFor on a POST of a form doesnt actually create a field that can be referenced back in the controller.  You would need to use an additional HiddenFor if you need to refer to fields in your submitted POST method.