# Change UiHint search path in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

By default `UiHint` attribute is looking for template in `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` or `Views/{Controller}/DisplayTemplate`. I really need to put my templates in different path so I am looking for solution that will make this work. Is there any way to add some other location to search places?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you set template in `DisplyFor` or `EditorFor`,... ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually as far as I know, [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841787/mvc-template-from-folder-other-than-default-editortemplates-displaytemplates?answertab=active#tab-top) change `UiHint`'s default location so instead you can simply set template this way:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyItem, "~/Views/Controller/DisplayTemplates/MyItem.cshtml")
```

Update: for having a template for your property you have three options:

Comment: Oh, no please! :( i can't do this for every field in my project. Actually on looking for templates, i want to say to the `RazorEngine` to look some other places before the defaults. this should be assignable in general way because maybe it be changed as a consequence of the my theme changed!

Comment: @AliAdlavaran So based on convention you have to put your template in those folders.