# One to Many View - do I have to use a View Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Say I have a view like this:

```
@model Models.CustomerModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    @*<h4>ApplicationModel</h4>*@
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Surname)
        </dd>
       </dl>
</div>
```

Say CustomerModel also has a collection of Orders.  The Order class looks like this:

```
public class Order {
public int OrderID {get; set; }
public datetime OrderDate {get; set; }
```

How can I put all the Orders liked to the Customer on the same view? I have tried this (under the code above):

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderID)
        </th>
    <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in model.Orders)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.OrderID)
        </td>
    <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The error I get is:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'orderid' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Delete(Int32)'.

If I remove the second fragment of code (for each loop), then it works properly.  How do I add the second fragment of code?

Comment: Using `foreach` is Ok. Where is the problem? Doesn't it work?

Comment: Your heading is somehow unrelated to the question, maybe I'm misunderstanding something. What's the problem?

Comment: @MegaTron, please see the last paragraph now.

Comment: @jAC, please see the last paragraph now.

Comment: The error is related to calling your `Delete()` method (and that has nothing to do with the code you have shown)

Comment: similar issue maybe related this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245365/mvc-the-parameters-dictionary-contains-a-null-entry-for-parameter-k-of-non-n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add null check

```
@if(Model.Orders != null)
{
  foreach (var item in Model.Orders)
  {
      <tr>
          <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(t => item.OrderID)
          </td>
      <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(t => item.Description)
          </td>
      </tr>
  }
}
```

or using LINQ you can

```
if(Model.Orders.Any())
```

if it doesn't help then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245365/mvc-the-parameters-dictionary-contains-a-null-entry-for-parameter-k-of-non-n)

Comment: The error I get with this is: "CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Because it has to be `Model`

Comment: Ohh, yes. Use "Model" not "model"

Comment: It now says: "A local or parameter named 'item' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Description)`. You cannot declare a new `item` in your lambda, if it's already used.

Comment: @w0051977 You did change it on both `DisplayFor`, didn't you?

Comment: @jAC, I rebuilt the project and it is working now.  Thanks.  What is m in the lambda expression? It is passed as an input parameter but is not used.

Comment: @w0051977 The part of the lambda before `=>` (here `t` or `m`) declares a variable, that references the `Model`, since `DisplayFor` usually directly should reference some `Model.Property` (e.g. `Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)`. This is a workaround to make `DisplayFor` work in a loop. If you're uncomfortable with it, simply use `Html.Display(item.Property)`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419711/how-can-i-use-html-displayfor-inside-of-an-iterator

Answer (score 0):

You can make OrderId Nullable in CustomerModel

```
public int? OrderID {get; set; }
```

OR check the Null value coming from Database for OrderId (If OrderId is not supposed to be Null then it's bad data and should be restricted from database itself)