# How to display item out of the foreach statement in MVC5 entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a index in controller and view following.
When I enter student ID on textbox search, I want to display information of student and list all activities of them. How to do that.
Thank you so much!

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Sid)
{
    var grad = db.Gradings.Include(g => g.Activity).Include(g => g.Student).Where(g => g.StudentID == Sid).ToList();      
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <p>
                Student ID: @Html.TextBox("Sid",ViewBag.FilterValue as string)
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
        }
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Activity Name</th>
                ....
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {   
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Activity.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Responsibility)</td>
                    ....
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
    <h3> Total score: @ViewBag.Total</h3>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to make the form a `FormMethod.Get` to post back to your `Index()` method, and then that method need to return the model to the view - `return View(grad);`

Comment: So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: when the code run, View display more student name record. How to display only one. I try to write the @Html.Displayfor(@model=>model.Student.Name) out of the foreach() statement, but it not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need one action to serve your view initially when the user requests it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();     
}
```

Then you need another action to process the user's request when the request submits the form:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Sid)
{
    var grad = db.Gradings.Include(g => g.Activity).Include(g => g.Student).Where(g => g.StudentID == Sid).ToList();  

    return View(grad);    
}
```

Now `grad` is a `List<Grading>` and above we are passing it to the view as the model so make sure you use it in your view. You may need to include the namespace for `List` and `Grading`:

```
@model List<Grading>
```

---

Finally instead of using `foreach` in your view, use a `for` loop so your HTML tags have unique IDs. Right now (with foreach), all `Grading` records will have the same name and id attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the view in using @model PagedList.IPagedList<ActivityScore.Models.Grading> Can you detail how to use the for loop?
i wan to display:
your name is: Student A
table:
Activity name      Score

instead table following:
Student Name     Activity name     Score
Student A            abv                        2
Student A            xyz                         2

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419711/how-can-i-use-html-displayfor-inside-of-an-iterator) if it helps.